# Why is str.format() better than str()?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, format, string-formatting

To convert a number into a string in python I used the `str()` function, but a few people suggested that I use `format()` instead. When I tried both, I got the same result:

```
n = 10  
print ['{}'.format(n)] # ['10']  
print [str(n)] # ['10']
```

Is there any significant difference?

Answer (score 2):

While [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) will give you a default string representation of a number, [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) allows you to specify how it is formatted.

Examples:

```
>>> '{:.3f}'.format(3.141592653589793)  # 3 decimal places
'3.142'

>>> '{:,d}'.format(1234567)  # thousand separators
'1,234,567'


>>> '{:6d}'.format(10)  # padded to six spaces
'    10'

>>> '{:05.2f}%'.format(8.497)  # zero-padded, 2 decimal places
'08.50%'

>>> '{:^6d}'.format(10)  # centered
'  10  '

>>> '{:x}'.format(1597463007)  # hexadecimal
'5f3759df'
```

You can also specify format strings involving multiple values:

```
>>> 'Customer #{cust_id:08d} owes ${bal:,.2f}'.format(bal=1234.5, cust_id=6789)
'Customer #00006789 owes $1,234.50'
```

There are many different options for format strings – the complete reference is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: And you can also have nested formats: `'{:.{}f}'.format(0.12345, 5) -> '0.12345'` while `'{:.{}f}'.format(0.12345, 2) -> 0.12`

Answer (score 0):

I will be a bit daring with my answer.. :-)

I don't think `str.format()` is better than `str()`. `str()` is shorter, and if it gives you what you want, it is great.

If you need to format the number with the amount of digits, for example, the `{}.format()` will do the job, but also `'%.3f' % n` will do the job just as well.

There are some advantages to `{}.format()` compared to `%` operator, and repeating an argument is one, but not so common. I still use `%` because it is shorter.

It seems like Python itself seeks constantly for better ways, and indeed in Python 3.6 they have come up with the best way, IMO, so far, which is common to some programming languages. Here it is, straight from the doc:

```
>>> name = "Fred"
>>> f"He said his name is {name}."
```

You can read more about it here:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: I agree. I still use ℅ in py34 but once I can use py36 I will use the f type. Just waiting for cython to settle

Answer (score 0):

This guy explains the many advantages of `format` over `str`:
https://pyformat.info/

If time is a concern, however, you might want to use `str`:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('str(25)', number=10000)
0.003485473003820516
>>> timeit.timeit('"{}".format(25)', number=10000)
0.00590304599609226
>>> timeit.timeit('str([2,5])', number=10000)
0.007156646002840716
>>> timeit.timeit('"{}".format([2,5])', number=10000)
0.017119816999183968
```